# Limit on maximum two rows per column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way in mysql to adapt this query:

```
select * from table order by date desc limit 4
```

so that each product only appears at most twice?

```
date | product | description  
2015 | a | alpha  
2012 | a | bravo  
2014 | a | charlie  
2011 | b | delta  
2000 | c | echo  
1999 | d | foxtrot
1972 | d | g...
```

The  query that should return:

```
2015 | a | alpha  
2014 | a | charlie  
2011 | b | delta  
2000 | c | echo
```

instead of

```
2015 | a | alpha  
2014 | a | charlie  
2012 | a | bravo
2011 | b | delta
```

Comment: why was the output in wrong order in first output with 2012 coming before 2014 in DESC ?

Comment: @DrewPierce the first example is how my table looks like, not the result of a query

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a query like this:

```
Select thedate, product, description
From (
  Select t.*
  , (@r:=Case when @p=t.Product then @r+1 else 1 end) as rownumber
  , (@p:=t.Product) as theProduct
  From (Select * From thetable order by product, thedate desc) t,
       (Select @r:=0,@p:='') r
) q
Where rownumber <= 2
```

(Note that I'm using `thedate` as my column name and `thetable` as my table name to avoid having to escape their names).

`Select @r:=0,@p:=''` is joined to the query to create two variables: @r to store the row number, and @p for the last product. If the product is the same as the last row we increment the row number, otherwise we reset it to 1.

This simulates the row_number() over Partition functionality available in SQL Server but not in MySQL. It assigns a number to each row in each group (where a group is the set of rows for a product), and then the WHERE clause limits the results so that only the first two row numbers for each group are shown.